# Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row (for all records)

Tags: mysql, sql

Here i need to get all the records group by AgentID but it showing error:Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

table :

```
 customerID  amountreceived date_time area agentID paymentmode
   1            2000         5/13/2014 hyd   1       cash


enter code here

 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE DEFINER=`ntc`@`%` PROCEDURE `spforallAgents`()
 BEGIN
select 
(select 
        @DayAmount:=sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountperday
    from
        collection_master
    where  day(Date_Time) = day(CURRENT_DATE())   group by AgentID),
(select 
        @MonthAmount:=sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountperday
    from
        collection_master
    where  date_time between DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') and LAST_DAY(now() - interval 0 month) group by AgentID),
    (select 
        @YearAmount:=sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountpermonth
    from
        collection_master where  year(Date_Time) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) group by AgentID),
 (select 
        @Position:=@Position + 1 AS Rank
    from
        collection_master,
        (SELECT @Position:=0) r group by AgentID) as position;

END
```

Comment: None of your sub queries seem to narrow down the results by AgentID, merely group by AgentID. As such each will bring back one record per AgentID

Comment: yes but as per data day amount is 2 records and month amount 3 records and agent id 3 records so how to check null  and assign null or  0 to column o/p value?

Comment: Do it as JOINs. I will give an example in a moment

Comment: no just for single table

Comment: You are using sub queries, but you can do a FROM the sub queries and can join them together rather than having them in the main SELECT clause. I can have more of a play if you post the table declare(s) with some sample data and the results you would like for that sample data.

Comment: please check the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using joins, you could do it something like this (untested):-

```
SELECT AgentID, 
        current_date_amount, 
        date_range_amount, 
        month_amount,
        @Position:=@Position + 1 AS `Rank`
FROM
(
    SELECT just_agent.AgentID, 
            total_current_date.Totoalamountperday AS current_date_amount, 
            total_date_range.Totoalamountperday AS date_range_amount, 
            total_month.Totoalamountpermonth AS month_amount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT AgentID
        FROM collection_master
    ) just_agent
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        select AgentID, SUM(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountperday
        from collection_master
        where  day(Date_Time) = day(CURRENT_DATE())
        group by AgentID
    ) total_current_date
    ON just_agent.AgentID = total_current_date.AgentID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        select AgentID, sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountperday
        from collection_master
        where  date_time between DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') and LAST_DAY(now() - interval 0 month) 
        group by AgentID
    ) total_date_range
    ON just_agent.AgentID = total_date_range.AgentID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        select AgentID, sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountpermonth
        from collection_master 
        where  year(Date_Time) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
        group by AgentID
    ) total_month
    ON just_agent.AgentID = total_month.AgentID
    ORDER BY total_month.Totoalamountpermonth DESC
) Sub1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Position:=0) Sub2
```

Note that this is making a few assumptions. For example your original query doesn't make it clear what order you want to use to assign the rank (I have assumed descending Totoalamountpermonth). Also it would be simpler if there were another table giving the agent IDs, rather than using an extra sub query to get the distinct AgentID

SQL fiddle for it:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/549232/2

EDIT

Joining the query against itself, using the code from the other thread (and M. Massias deserves the credit).

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT AgentID, 
            current_date_amount, 
            date_range_amount, 
            month_amount,
            @Position1:=@Position1 + 1 AS `Rank`
    FROM
    (
        SELECT just_agent.AgentID, 
                total_current_date.Totoalamountperday AS current_date_amount, 
                total_date_range.Totoalamountperday AS date_range_amount, 
                total_month.Totoalamountpermonth AS month_amount
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT AgentID
            FROM collection_master
        ) just_agent
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            select AgentID, SUM(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountperday
            from collection_master
            where  day(Date_Time) = day(CURRENT_DATE())
            group by AgentID
        ) total_current_date
        ON just_agent.AgentID = total_current_date.AgentID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            select AgentID, sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountperday
            from collection_master
            where  date_time between DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') and LAST_DAY(now() - interval 0 month) 
            group by AgentID
        ) total_date_range
        ON just_agent.AgentID = total_date_range.AgentID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            select AgentID, sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountpermonth
            from collection_master 
            where  year(Date_Time) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
            group by AgentID
        ) total_month
        ON just_agent.AgentID = total_month.AgentID
        ORDER BY total_month.Totoalamountpermonth DESC
    ) Sub1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Position1:=0) Sub2
) t1
JOIN 
(
    SELECT AgentID, 
            current_date_amount, 
            date_range_amount, 
            month_amount,
            @Position2:=@Position2 + 1 AS `Rank`
    FROM
    (
        SELECT just_agent.AgentID, 
                total_current_date.Totoalamountperday AS current_date_amount, 
                total_date_range.Totoalamountperday AS date_range_amount, 
                total_month.Totoalamountpermonth AS month_amount
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT AgentID
            FROM collection_master
        ) just_agent
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            select AgentID, SUM(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountperday
            from collection_master
            where  day(Date_Time) = day(CURRENT_DATE())
            group by AgentID
        ) total_current_date
        ON just_agent.AgentID = total_current_date.AgentID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            select AgentID, sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountperday
            from collection_master
            where  date_time between DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') and LAST_DAY(now() - interval 0 month) 
            group by AgentID
        ) total_date_range
        ON just_agent.AgentID = total_date_range.AgentID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            select AgentID, sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountpermonth
            from collection_master 
            where  year(Date_Time) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
            group by AgentID
        ) total_month
        ON just_agent.AgentID = total_month.AgentID
        ORDER BY total_month.Totoalamountpermonth DESC
    ) Sub1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Position2:=0) Sub2
) t2
ON ABS(t1.`Rank` - t2.`Rank`) <= 1.5 
WHERE t1.AgentID = 2
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'total_current_date.Totoalamountperday' in 'field list'

Comment: Try that. but please post table layouts, etc, so I have some chance of testing it.

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'just_agent.AgentID' in 'field list'

Comment: Given it a quick test in SQL fiddle. Try the version now above

Comment: one more doubt here if i select agentID-2 ex his rank is 2 only how can i show 1,2 and 3 records?i.e his before rank and after rank records

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. The above query needs to get all the records to determine the rank. If you put a check in there for the AgentID then it would only bring back one (with a rank of 1). You could use the above as a sub query in a FROM clause, and then check the AgentID

Comment: If iput a check in there for the AgentID exam-2 then it would only bring back three records like his record ,before rank record and after rank record

Comment: Afraid I can't think of an efficient way of doing that. Only SQL way I can think of would be to pretty much repeat the above query twice, once with a check for AgentID in it (after the rank is calculated) and join that to another copy of the query with an ON clause to check the rank matches the first, or is 1 greater or 1 less.

Comment: shall ask as another question could u please give me example over there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631649/how-to-get-three-records-based-on-agentid-and-rank-in-mysql

Comment: hi @Kickstart can u give me ur solution as u suggested?

Comment: Added it, doing the join as suggested by M. Massias in the other thread

Comment: but how to do that in stored procedure?

Comment: You can just use that in a stored proc. You could also just set up the basic sub query as a view and just join the views together.

Comment: thank you very much for both M. Massias and kickstart

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52752/discussion-between-sandeep-and-kickstart)