# How to get three records based on agentID and rank in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to get the three records i.e his record,previous rank record and after rank record 
I had SP in below fiddle:

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE DEFINER=`ntc`@`%` PROCEDURE `stckrank`()
BEGIN
SELECT AgentID, 
    current_day_amount, 
    month_amount, 
    year_amount,
    @Position:=@Position + 1 AS `Rank`
FROM
(
SELECT just_agent.AgentID, 
        total_current_date.Totoalamountperday AS current_day_amount, 
        total_current_month.Totoalamountpermonth AS month_amount, 
        total_year.Totoalamountperyear AS year_amount
     FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT AgentID
    FROM collection
) just_agent
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    select AgentID, SUM(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountperday
    from collection
    where  day(Date_Time) = day(CURRENT_DATE())
    group by AgentID
) total_current_date
ON just_agent.AgentID = total_current_date.AgentID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    select AgentID, sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountpermonth
    from collection
    where  date_time between DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') and LAST_DAY(now() - interval 0 month) 
    group by AgentID
) total_current_month
ON just_agent.AgentID = total_current_month.AgentID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    select AgentID, sum(AmountRecevied) as Totoalamountperyear
    from collection
    where  year(Date_Time) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
    group by AgentID
) total_year
ON just_agent.AgentID = total_year.AgentID
ORDER BY total_year.Totoalamountperyear DESC
) Sub1
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Position:=0) Sub2;
END
```

output:

```
agentiid dayamount monthamount yearamount rank
 2        3000       4000          7000   1
 1        2000      3000           5000   2
 3         200       300            500   3
 4         100       100            200    4
```

now if i select agent id 2 i need to get below record and no record for above so null or 0 should show

select agent id -2
Need to show or get 
        his rank record and after record

```
agentiid dayamount monthamount yearamount rank
    2        3000       4000          7000   1
    1        2000      3000           5000   2
```

Comment: Your fiddle is deranged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it joining the table to itself on a rank condition:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM yourTable t1
JOIN yourTable t2
ON ABS(t1.rank - t2.rank) <= 1.5 --is this what you want ?
WHERE t1.agentiid = 2
```

[This SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6277a8/2) provides the desired results.

With this join, each row in your original table is associated to itself (always) and to the line with previous and next rank (if they exist).

Comment: have u checked my fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/549232/2 here i want to get

Comment: ok first i had table agentid,amountreceived,datetime here amountreceived column i divided into threecolumns sum(dayamount),sum(monthamount),sum(yearamount) where agentid=agentid using storedprocedure in that i assign the rank so i am asking how to do there

Comment: i assigned each select query as table so i am asking how do in sp

Comment: @M.Massias - this is following on from another question (the fiddle is my response to that other question). I think the basic concept you have here would do the job, just using the query from the sqlfiddle as sub queries rather than using the tables in your SQL (would need to change the variable names I think, otherwise the ranks would probably be corrupted). But I very much doubt is would be quick!

Comment: @Kickstart - Sorry, but how was I supposed to know this was the result from another question ? I was provided with an input and a desired output, and I think my query does get this result, doesn't it ?

Comment: thank you very much for both M. Massias and kickstart